# Read Column Families list from Cassandra server

Tags: cassandra, astyanax

I'm making a Cassandra data viewer using Astyanax, and I want to be able to list the column families that are on a Cassandra Keyspace without having a predefined schema.
For now, I'm listing the column families from a JSON Schema, and not from Cassandra itself.

Unfortunately, I didn't find anything in Astyanax's documentation allowing this.
Any way to solve this out? I thought about using CQL, although I never used it before.

Thanks in advance, and sorry if I wasn't specific enough about what I'm trying to do, or the information I provided. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering myself since I found out.

You can get the CF List using an AstyanaxContext object and using:

`astyanaxContext.getClient().describeKeyspace().getColumnFamilyList()`

Hope it will help if someone get stuck with the same issue.